# Is it safe to execute bookmarklet from extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet

**Background:**

I wrote an extension to search bookmarks and open the URL for the user.

I've added JavaScript bookmarklet support to the extension and now it is invoking the script by something similar to this code:

```
var bookmark_address; // the address containing javascript:blah();
var js = bookmark_address.substr(11);
chrome.tabs.executeScript({'code': js});
```

Previously I had been using this code:

```
var bookmark_address; // the address containing javascript:blah();
chrome.tabs.update({'url': bookmark_address});
```

The first one seems better, but they don't actually have much differences. Both of them requires the permissions `["tabs", "<all_urls>"]`. I am now requesting the permissions only when the user choose to enable bookmarklet support (by [optional permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions.html)).

**Problem:**

I just thought of the security problem. Bookmarks are added by users so they are *usually* safe, but because my extension "invoke" the script, it is executed in the context of my extension. The script will be able to mess up my extension's local storage and variables. **Moreover, the script executed might have permission to perform Cross-Origin `XMLHttpRequest`.** [(Docs)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)

Am I thinking it correctly? Is there really a security problem? Is there any way to "sandbox" the script execution from my extension, and/or disable the permission for the script?

It could be a very bad thing for users of the extension, so please consider the problem seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested cross-origin XHR with the following bookmarklet (of course with `javascript:` appended):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.open("POST", "http://jsfiddle.net/echo/json/", true);
xhr.send("json=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"foo": "bar"})));
```

**Result:**

- Clicking on the bookmark does **not** permit cross-origin XHR.
- Using `chrome.tabs.update` does **not** permit cross-origin XHR.
- Using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` **does** permit cross-origin XHR.

**Conclusion:**

Using `chrome.tabs.update` to execute bookmarklets is basically as safe as clicking on the bookmark normally, while `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is **not** suitable for executing bookmarklets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most secure solution is to append the script to the page inside script tags. I think that this will work most similarly to how normal bookmarklets work, and will not give the code extra permissions. It may be even better if the script is then immediately removed.